# How to force Web API to throw an error when receiving an unmapped field in the request json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a REST API using Web API. The problem I am having is that the JSON serializer is not rejecting unmapped fields. Assuming I have a simple object like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
 public bool MyBool { get; set; }
 public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a simple controller which accepts an object of this type in the body of a request

```
public void Post(MyClass instace)
{
   ...
}
```

Now, I post a request to the endpoint of this controller with the following JSON in the body of the request:

{
        "MyBool":true,
        "MyString":"Valid",
        "InvalidField":"Invalid"
      }

Currently, the controller will quietly accept this request, mapping true to MyBool, and "Valid" to MyString while ignoring the InvalidField. How can I change this so that an error is thrown whenever an invalid field is present?

Comment: Deserialize the JSON yourself using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject(v=vs.110).aspx for instance and then use reflection to see if the deserialized object has more properties than your model, in which case there were additional (invalid) fields in the JSON request.

Comment: Is there a specific purpose that you need this validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `Required` is not what you are looking for, since you are interested in extra fields that are present in the request. `Required` is for fields that are absent. You can read the JSON yourself and validate but to me that is a lot of work. So, piggy backing on binding is what something I would look at. I just wrote a small blog post to answer this question. Check it out http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/detecting-extra-fields-in-asp-net-web-api-request/.

Comment: Great little blog post.  I tried to implement this for my project, but am only a beginner in C# and the new versions seem not to work with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `Required` attribute to your member:

```
public class MyClass
{
 [Required]
 public bool MyBool { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx

Comment: You need to be careful with the `Required` data annotations and value types. Even if `MyBool` was not passed in the request body, it will have a value of `false` and will pass the validation.

Comment: From my experience, if MyBool was not posted it would have a value of false but would also have a model validation error in the modelstate.